# NumPy dot product: take product of vector products (rather than sum)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Say i have two matrices: `M` is 2x3, and `C` is 3x4...

```
import numpy as np
M = np.matrix([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
C = np.matrix([ [1,1,2,2], [1,2,1,2], [2,1,1,1]])
```

I need to multiply these matrices to get a result of size 2x4. This would be easy with `np.dot(M, C)`, but i want to multiply the vector products rather than sum them.

For example, a regular dot product would do:

```
result[0,0] = (M[0,0]*C[0,0]) + (M[0,1]*C[1,0]) + (M[0,2]*C[2,0])
# result[0,0] = (1*1) + (2*1) + (3*2)
# result[0,0] = 9
```

I simply want to replace the plus signs with multiplication signs...

```
result[0,0] = (M[0,0]*C[0,0]) * (M[0,1]*C[1,0]) * (M[0,2]*C[2,0])
# result[0,0] = (1*1) * (2*1) * (3*2)
# result[0,0] = 12
```

My best solution has relied on looping over rows of `M` --

```
result = np.empty( (2,4) )
for i in range(2):
    result[i,:] = np.prod(np.multiply(np.tile(M[i,:].T , (1,4)), C) , axis=0)
```

Breaking that down, each row of `M` is transposed, then tiled (using `np.tile`) so it is the same size as `C` (i.e., 3x4). Then i multiply the matrices element-wise, and take the product of each column.

In the actual program i'm writing, `M` and `C` are not necessarily integer, can be of any size, and this calculation is carried out many thousands of times. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this that is quick and readable.

### UPDATE

@Warren Weckesser offered a great solution. But now i have a new challenge--specifically, what if i wanted to subtract a number from the vector products prior to multiplying them?

This can be done like so in my earlier solution:

```
result1 = np.empty( (2,4) ) 
for i in range(2): 
    result1[i,:] = np.prod( 1 - np.multiply( np.tile(M[i,:].T , (1,4)), C) , axis=0)
```

I have played around with the solution provided by @Warren Weckesser, to no avail. I would absolutely love to figure out something more elegant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way:

```
In [68]: M
Out[68]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])

In [69]: C
Out[69]: 
matrix([[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 1, 2],
        [2, 1, 1, 1]])

In [70]: M.prod(axis=1) * C.prod(axis=0)
Out[70]: 
matrix([[ 12,  12,  12,  24],
        [240, 240, 240, 480]])
```

`M.prod(axis=1)` is the product of the elements in the rows of `M`.  Because `M` is a `matrix` instance, the shape of the result is (2, 1):

```
In [71]: M.prod(axis=1)
Out[71]: 
matrix([[  6],
        [120]])
```

Similarly, `C.prod(axis=0)` is the product down the columns of `C`:

```
In [72]: C.prod(axis=0)
Out[72]: matrix([[2, 2, 2, 4]])
```

Then the matrix product of these two matrices, with shape (2, 1) and (1, 4), has shape (2, 4), and it contains the products that you want.

With arrays, use the `keepdims` argument of `prod()` to maintain the 2D shapes, and use the `dot()` method instead of `*`:

```
In [79]: m = M.A

In [80]: c = C.A

In [81]: m
Out[81]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [82]: c
Out[82]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1]])

In [83]: m.prod(axis=1, keepdims=True).dot(c.prod(axis=0, keepdims=True))
Out[83]: 
array([[ 12,  12,  12,  24],
       [240, 240, 240, 480]])
```

Comment: this is great! Thanks. Do you have any advice about what i would do if i wanted to subtract something from the vector products before multiplying them? i.e.,

result = np.empty( (2,4) )
for i in range(2):
    result[i,:] = np.prod( 1 - np.multiply(np.tile(M[i,:].T , (1,4)), C) , axis=0)